# Как осуществить выборку записей из таблицы без определныых значений полей

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, требуется вывести таблицу пользователей для последующих манипуляций, типа выставления ролей\прав\уровня доступа.

Проблема в том, что админ может свергнуть сам себя, выставив себе любое другое значение, а это мне не нужно.

Как осуществить выборку записей из таблицы без определенных значений полей, типа:

```
table::find()->where(['id' != 1])
```

Для разграничения прав использую RBAC, может с ней как то можно повозиться чтобы убрать эту дыру...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение следующее:

```
Table::find()->where(['!=','id', 1])->all()
```

Если вы используете поисковую модель, тогда решение следующее:

```
    $query = self::find()->where(['!=', 'id', 1]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query'      => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 15,
        ]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    $query->andFilterWhere([Ваши фильтры]);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: о, уже 2-жды мне помогаете. но я использую searchFilter и при Вашем решении появляется другая ошибка. `Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on array`  на строке `$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])` в той же модели.

Comment: Ответил, дописал свой ответ

Comment: в принципе у меня все так и было, однако решением оказалось удаление `->all()` в `Table::find()->where(['!=','id', 1])->all()`
поправьте, пожалуйста, ответ.

Comment: Да, я в ответе дополнил, что там должно быть дез него. Т.к через поисковую модель all() не используется

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за помощь.